# I don't understand the code line "temp.next = this;" in this Java example

Tags: java

I was trying to understand the use of keyword "this" in Java and ended up having trouble of understand line 17, 18, 22, and 25 with this example:

```
1.public class LinkMeUp
2.{
3.    private int data;
4.    private LinkMeUp next;
5.    
6.    LinkMeUp(int num)
7.    {
8.         data = num * num; next = null;
9.    }
10.    LinkMeUp()
11.    {
12.        this(0);
13.    }
14.    LinkMeUp add(int num)
15.    {
16.        LinkMeUp temp = new LinkMeUp(num);
17.        temp.next = this;
18.        return(temp);
19.    }
20.    void print()
21.    {
22.        LinkMeUp temp = this;
23.        while(temp != null)
24.        {
25.             System.out.println(temp.data);
26.             temp = temp.next;
27.        }
28.    }
29.    public static void main(String[] args)
30.    {
31.        LinkMeUp link = new LinkMeUp();
32.        for(int k =1; k < 10; k++)
33.             link = link.add(k);
34.        link.print();
35.    }
36.}
```

I understand in the main method, the LinkMeUp object is created and assigned the memory address to link. It will then goes to the default constructor LinkMeUp().

The code line this(0) inside the default constructor will call the other constructor LinkMeUp(int num) and set data = 0 * 0 = 0 and next = null.

Then it goes back to main method into the loop, passes the first k = 1 to the add(int num) method. Inside the add(int num) method, it creates another LinkMeUp object and assigns to reference temp.

I don't understand the temp.next = this; Is "this" referred to LinkMeUp class or LinkMeUp(int num)? I don't understand temp.next since "next" is not a helper method but another reference to LinkMeUp object, which is assigned to null in the LinkMeUp(int num) constructor.

I also have trouble understanding line 22 and 25

By the way, here is the output of the program

```
81
64
49
36
25
16
9
4
1
0
```

Comment: if `this` is not used to call an overloaded constructor it will allways refer to the current class scope and though refer to the current instance. In this case `temp.next = this` `temp.next` will refer to the current class instance of `LinkMeUp`.

Comment: I think "this" in this example refers to a overloaded constructor; however, when I test to print out "this" right below line 17, I got this as my output

Comment: LinkMeUp@5ac64b++LinkMeUp@1ffec19++LinkMeUp@3e20c8++LinkMeUp@84f820++LinkMeUp@ba1965++LinkMeUp@51bf0f++LinkMeUp@146f46d++LinkMeUp@985f9d++LinkMeUp@d31a9a++81
64

Comment: keyword "this" contains the memory address of the LinkMeUp objects

Comment: By far, the best way to understand things like this is to use your debugger and step through the code statement-by-statement.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand the temp.next = this; Is "this" referred to LinkMeUp class or LinkMeUp(int num)?

Neither. That line is in the `add` method, so `this` is a reference to the current `LinkMeUp` **instance**, not a constructor. (Even in a constructor, since it's not *called* — e.g., `this()` — it wouldn't be invoking a constructor.) `LinkMeUp.add` creates a new instance of `LinkMeUp` via `LinkMeUp(num)`, sets its `next` member to `this`, and returns it. So now the current instance (on which `add` was called) is the `next` on the new instance `add` creates, which is returned.

In the loop in `main`, we see that the instance `add` creates is retained:

```
link = link.add(k);
```

So that's how the chain is getting created.

Let's follow the logic through:

1. `main` creates an instance of `LinkMeUp` using the no-parameters constructor, so we have a single instance whose `data` is `0`:

```
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
link−−−−−−>|  LinkMeUp  |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
           | data: 0    |
           | next: null |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

2. Then we go into the loop with `k == 1` and call `link = link.add(k);`. `add` calls `new LinkMeUp(1)` which creates a new instance and sets its `data` to `1`, sets that new instance's `next` to the current instance, and returns it; the `link = link.add(k);` line updates `link`, and so after all that we have:

```
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
link−−−−−−>|  LinkMeUp  |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
           | data: 1    |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
           | next       |−−−−>|  LinkMeUp  |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                              | data: 0    |
                              | next: null |
                              +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note how the first instance (`data === 0`) is now at the end of the chain, and `link` refers to the new instance returned by `add` (`data === 1`).

3. Then the loop continues with `k == 2` and calls `link = link.add(k);` again, which creates and returns a new instance with `data == 4` (`2 * 2`). After that we have:

```
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−+          
link−−−−−−>|  LinkMeUp  |          
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−+          
           | data: 4    |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+                        
           | next       |−−−−>|  LinkMeUp  |                        
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+                        
                              | data: 1    |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+     
                              | next       |−−−−>|  LinkMeUp  |     
                              +−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+     
                                                 | data: 0    |
                                                 | next: null |
                                                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

...and so on until after `k == 9`.

> I also have trouble understanding line 22 and 25

Line 22:

```
LinkMeUp temp = this;
```

...sets the variable `temp` to the current instance (the one created by `add(k)` when `k` was `9`). Then while that varible is `!= null`, we loop, outputting `temp.data`. So the first loop, it will output `81` (the `data` on the instance created via `add(k)` when `k == 9`). Then line 26:

```
temp = temp.next;
```

...takes us to the next entry in the chain, which is the instance created by `add(k)` when `k` was `8`. We output its `data` value (`64`). Then we keep looping until we reach the end of the chain, `temp == null`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The answer is crystal clear and thoughtful. It gives me deeper understanding of objects and classes.

Answer (score 0):

At line 17 and 22, "temp.next = this", LinkMeUp temp = this.
You are calling print() and add() on some object that got created. So when you refer "this" in those methods it simply means you are referring to the method's object("this" when used at any method refers to its own Object).